# Show page:2 directly in View page in CAKEPHP

Tags: cakephp-2.1

Is there any option in `$this->Paginator->Settings()` to paginate a table and store second or third page to the variable using

```
$view=$this->Paginate('Post');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the page with the following:

```
$this->Paginate->settings(array('page' => 2));
$posts = $this->Paginate->paginate('Post');
```

`$posts` now contains the records for page `2`